# Ruby OptionParser: 2 options, 1 argument

Tags: ruby, parameters, optionparser

I am attempting to use OptionParser to read in multiple options and have them all act on a single filename. `Ex: myprogram.rb -a -b file.txt` How can I make 2 options share a mandatory argument while also allowing things like `-h` to run without parameters? Currently the above line just makes `-a` take `-b` as its parameter.

```
optionparser.on("-a FILENAME", "Do this") do |a|
  puts a
end
optionparser.on("-b FILENAME", "Do that") do |b|
  puts b
end
```

**EDIT:**

What it is doing:

```
myprogram.rb -a -b file.txt
=> -b
```

What I need it to do:

```
myprogram.rb -a -b file.txt
=> file.txt
=> file.txt
```

**Note:**

These commands should be able to run independently as well as concurrently similar to `ls -a ..`, `ls -l ..` and `ls -a -l ..` However NEITHER command should work if there is no filename given. Ideally this solution should work with any *n* number of options.

Comment: Docs reference http://ruby-doc.org/stdlib-1.9.3/libdoc/optparse/rdoc/OptionParser.html

Answer (score 0):

What I have right now is:

```
alpha=false
beta=false
optionparser.on("-a", "Do this") do |a|
  alpha = a
end
optionparser.on("-b", "Do that") do |b|
  beta = b
end
if alpha
  #do something with ARGV[0]
end
if beta
  #do something with ARGV[0]
end
```

This code assumes that after the options are taken, the only thing left on the command line should be the filename. I feel like there is a more elegant way of doing this that takes into account other things potentially cluttering the command line and allows error correction for them.